# Списки в Python. Как можно сделать чтобы один индекс (например[0]) хранил несколько элементов? Спасибо!

Tags: python, list

```
l = [ ]

for i in range(10):
    l.append(  (x1[i], y1-y, x2[i], y2-y, width)  )  
    y -=40
```

`ev3.screen.draw_line(l[0])` - в индексе 0 должно быть это все: x1[i], y1-y, x2[i], y2-y, width

Comment: В показанном коде и так добавляете несколько элементов в один индекс через append. Что не так?

Comment: `ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0])`.

Comment: Вы смотрели, что у вас в `l` получается? Там список кортежей, и в элементе `0` тоже кортеж лежит из именно тех элементов, которые вы хотели.